# Simplexml Object Node Iteration

Tags: php, xml, iteration

I have an XML file that I'm parsing with PHP's Simplexml, but I'm having an issue with an iteration through nodes.

The XML:

```
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <category>Cat1</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <category>Cat1</category>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Title3</title>
    <category>Cat2</category>
  </item>
</channel>
```

My counting function:

```
public function cat_count($cat) {
    $count = 0;
    $items = $this->xml->channel->item;
    $size  = count($items);

    for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        if ($items[$i]->category == $cat) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Am I overlooking an error in my code, or is there another preferred method for iterating through the nodes? I've also used a foreach and while statement with no luck, so I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

EDIT: while using the xpath method below, I noticed that using

```
foreach ($this->xml->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->category;
}
```

will print all the category name, but, using

```
foreach ($this->xml->channel->item as $item) {
    if ($item->category == $cat) {
        echo $item->category;
    }
}
```

will only print one instance of the doubled categories. Even when I have copy and pasted the lines, only one shows. Does this mean the XML structure could be invalid somehow?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting. My mobile doesn't play well with the editor. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: item is repeated multiple times, so should be iterated over, or referenced as $this->xml->channel->item[0], $this->xml->channel->item[1], etc

Comment: That's what I'm doing, actually. Just mistyped it. I've updated the code.

Comment: I think the line `$size = count($size);` is supposed to be `$size = count($items);`, right?

Comment: It is. Another typo. Sorry, guys.

Comment: You should better isolate and test your code (it's also actually needed that you do so for the example codes you post here on Stackoverflow). That prevents you from doing clear mistakes, for example what you write in your edit is not true: https://eval.in/private/8a29d9476ac460 - both methods to iterate work as outlined in the [*SimpleXML Basic Examples*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) (suggested reading). For SimpleXML and `count` quite some questions have been asked already so if you refer to something new, I'm happy to answer if you still can't find it, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to count elements with a given name in an XML file is to use xpath. Try this:

```
private function categoryCount($categoryName) {
    $categoryName = $this->sanitize($categoryName); // easy xpath injection protection
    return count($this->xml->xpath("//item[category='$categoryName']"));
}
```

The sanitize() function should remove single and double quotes in your `$categoryName` to prevent xpath injection. To also get queries for a category name containing quotes to work, you need to build your xpath query string depending on wheather it contains single or double quotes:

```
// xpath in case of single quotes in category name
$xpath = '//item[category="' . $categoryName . '"]';

// xpath in case of double quotes in category name
$xpath = "//item[category='" . $categoryName . "']";
```

If you don't have full control over the xml data (for example if is created out of user generated content), you should take this into account. Unfortunately there is no simple way to this in php like parametrized queries.

see here for the php xpath function docs: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

see here for an xpath reference:  http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks for that info. While I still can't get it to work in this situation, I will be utilizing it in other methods in the class. I'm about to edit the original post with some updated debug info.

Comment: Sorry, there was a little bug in my answer: The $categoryName in the xpath expression needed to be in single quotes. I justed tested it at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it looks good now.

Comment: The code you've posted is prone to XPath injection. As this is a question related to not so experienced programmers, do not skip this important pat in your answer if you suggest xpath. See: [*Mitigating XPath Injection Attacks in PHP*](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/) which also provides reference to existing Stackoverflow answers regarding this topic.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, I had no idea about XML injection as I haven't had to use it much in the past. Thanks for the code and references, all.